# Dataset Empty parameter value

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have an xml dataset, I want to parametrize the compression type to treat .xml and .xml.gz files with the same pipeline :

When I put 'gzip' value in compression type it reads xml.gzip file. I want to know what value I should put to read uncompressed .xml file because it does not accept empty value. It is able to read xml file just when I delete the compression_type parameter

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should pass "None" and it should work out .

Answer (score 0):

I feel "None" is more of a workaround in this particular case.  "None" is still a string value, not empty.

In my scenario right now, I have an Excel dataset.  I want to make every parameter as generic as possible, including the file path/name, sheet name, and the range.  The value of "Range" under Connection tab allows empty value.  However if I specify it as @dataset().DataRange and leave my parameter DataRange empty, I cannot preview the data or submit the pipeline because it complains that the value cannot be empty.